# Django4.0 ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-4.0

I use translation in my Django apps. Since I installed Django version 4, when I try to import `ugettexget_lazy` as shown in the code below

```py
from django.utils.translation import ugettexget_lazy as _
```

I get the following error:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was removed from Django 4, use this instead

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

Comment: a batter solution is 1. replacing the requirement django-jsonfield==1.4.1 with django-jsonfield-backport==1.0.5
2. adding django-jsonfield-backport in settings to installed apps
3. replacing the import in our model file from 
from jsonfield import JSONField to from django.db.models import JSONField
4. rebuilding the migration files